# Are custom metadata values for GCE instance stored securely?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I was wondering if custom metadata for google compute engine VM instances was an appropriate place to store sensitive information for configuring apps that run on the instance.

So we use container-optimised OS images to run microservices.  We configure the containers with environment variables for things like creds for db connections and other systems we integrate with.

The VMs are treated as ephemeral for each CD deployment and the best I have come up with so far is to create an instance template with config values loaded via a file I keep on my local machine into the VM custom metadata, which is then made available to a systemctl unit when the VM starts up (cloud-config).

The essence of this means environment variable values (some containing creds) are uploaded by me (which don't change very much) and are then pulled from the VM instance metadata server when a new VM is fired up.  So I'm just wondering if there's any significant security concerns with this approach...

Many thanks for your help

Comment: What would you consider to be sensitive information?  How is that sensitive information used?  How would you manage that information?  Is it subject to change over time and if so how would you manage that change?  Do you require auditing of access and/or usage?   I'm tempted to say that the use of meta data isn't great for sensitive information.  Perhaps store it on Google Cloud Storage in a file that can be read only by the service id that the Compute Engine runs as.

Comment: Hey, Ben welcome to StackOverflow, you should describe your question with more details and any reference you have seen so that we can help you easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Compute Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) :

> Is metadata information secure?
>
> When you make a request to get
>   information from the metadata server, your request and the subsequent
>   metadata response never leaves the physical host running the virtual
>   machine instance.

Since the request and response are not leaving the physical host, you will not be able to access the metadata from another VM or from outside Google Cloud Platform. However, any user with access the VM will be able to query the metadata server and retrieve the information.

Based on the information you provided, storing credentials for a test or staging environment in this manner would be acceptable. However, if this is a production system with customer or information important to the business, I would keep the credentials in a secure store that tracks access. The data in the metadata server is not encrypted, and accesses are not logged.